# Tracking On-Time Performance for Allegiant: Why do Flight Numbers Keep Changing?

Tags: air-travel, flight-search-engines, allegiant-air

I frequently use services like flightaware to look up flights I am thinking about purchasing. Under normal circumstances (at least in the US) such as [this one](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/DAL1), searching for a flight number generally gives me a little bit of insight into whether the flight is usually delayed, what the actually flight time is, etc. That's because the flight gets the same flight number each day.

I was recently trying to do the same with Allegiant, and this has proven to be much more difficult. I can't tell for sure, but it seems like some (or all) of their routes change flight numbers regularly. For example, on the next few Thursdays, Allegiant is using flight numbers 2505, 2829, and 2887, all for the once-daily flight from Concord, NC (USA) to Orlando-Sanford (SFB). Flights operating on different days have other (still different) numbers. What's going on here? Is there any way to track Allegiant's performance on a given route over time, or is their approach simply too opaque?

Comment: FlightStats seems to have a feature to search historical flight data by route, which would seem to be helpful in your situation, but they charge $25/month for it.